# pdfminer3 is not extracting the text from colored pdf pages, how to convert pdf page into grayscale?

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction, grayscale, pdfminer

I am extracting the text from pdf using pdfminer3 library. But it is not working well in colored pages. I tried the following code to extract text from pdf:

```
from pdfminer3.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer3.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer3.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer3.converter import TextConverter
import io

resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle, laparams=LAParams())
page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)

with open("pdffile.pdf", 'rb') as fh:
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh,caching=True,check_extractable=True):
        page_interpreter.process_page(page)
    text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
f1=open("pdftext.txt","w+",encoding="utf8")
for i in text:
    f1.write(str(i))

# close open handles
converter.close()
fake_file_handle.close()

print(text)
```

It only extracting the data from some files very well. But from colored area it extract the data like this:

```
(cid:7)(cid:1)(cid:4)(cid:1)(cid:9)(cid:16)(cid:20)(cid:17)

(cid:10)(cid:15)(cid:14)(cid:1)(cid:16)(cid:20)(cid:17)

(cid:1)(cid:14)(cid:18)(cid:1)(cid:12) (cid:18)(cid:1)(cid:19)(cid:2)(cid:1)(cid:17)(cid:9)

(cid:18)(cid:20)(cid:12)(cid:19)(cid:1)(cid:14)(cid:16)(cid:20)(cid:17)
```

which is not how my data looks like in pdf. It is an simple alphanumeric data. I don't know why is it showing **cid:** it is not even in my pdf file.

Can anyone tells me how to convert pdf into grayscale pdf page. So i can use pdfminer. I don't want to convert the pdf into image and then into grascale, which i already done as pytesseract is not extracting the data well from this.

I also tried pdfplumber but it is also not giving me the correct data. Or can anyone suggest me the library which extract text from the image except pytesseract.

**Finally, i convert the pdf page into gray scale using online converter tool. And when i try to extract the data from it, it gives the same output as i mention above. So, i guess the fault is in pdfminer or in my code. How to resolve this problem.**

This is the one of pdf file from which i tried to extract text it gives the blank output : [Pdf file](https://gofile.io/d/9n7ipr)

Comment: As you already found out, the color does not interfere with text extraction. We don't have your PDF, so we can only make (educated) guesses. My guess would be that the fonts used on that page simply don't contain the information required for text extraction.

Comment: it is a newspaper page pdf. i want to extract article from it. Some pages it work fine and in some it will not. also there is not so much difference between the pages.

Comment: Can you share the pdf in question? If you share it, people here can try and analyze any issue coming up. The information you have given until now indicate that most likely the information for text extraction are missing, but it is possible that said analysis will turn up something different.

Comment: Sorry but i can't share the pdf because of some policies. but i tried many pdf files it only works in some of the pdfs and in some it just returns the blank not even single character

Comment: In that case all i can say is that most likely the information for text extraction are missing.

Comment: So, i tried pdfminer3 on a sample pdf file but it gives the blank output i upload that in the question please take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Your example PDF merely wraps a bitmap image of some newspaper page.

Text extraction on the other hand extracts text from text drawing instructions in PDFs, not bitmap images.

To retrieve text from PDFs like that you have to apply OCR.

Comment: How you find out it is a bitmap image? i tried the ocr as i tried to extract the text using pytesseract after converting it into grayscale but it does not gives the correct output as some pixels mixups.

Comment: I used a tool to browse the internal structure of the pdf. Itext RUPS to be precise. There are similar products by other manufacturers, too, e.g. PDFBox PDFDebugger. There also is such a tool in Adobe Acrobat Preflight.

Comment: Then what should i have to do to make it extractable for pdfminner3

Comment: Pdfminer is a tool for text extraction, I.e. a tool for extracting text from text drawing instructions in pdfs. Pdfs like your example don't contain text drawing instructions, only bitmaps. Thus, pdfminer is the wrong tool for retrieving text there. Instead use a tool for ocr.